# C: read string into dynamic array

Tags: c

Hi im trying to read user input of "unlimited" length into an char array. It works fine for shorter strings, but for more than around 30 characters the programm crashes. Why does this happen and how can i fix this?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char* read_string_from_terminal()//reads a string of variable length and returns a pointer to it
{
    int length = 0; //counts number of characters
    char c; //holds last read character
    char *input;

    input = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char)); //Allocate initial memory

    if(input == NULL) //Fail if allocating of memory not possible
    {
        printf("Could not allocate memory!");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    while((c = getchar()) != '\n') //until end of line
    {
        realloc(input, (sizeof(char))); //allocate more memory
        input[length++] = c; //save entered character
    }

    input[length] = '\0'; //add terminator
    return input;

}

int main()
{
    printf("Hello world!\n");
    char* input;
    printf("Input string, finish with Enter\n");
    input = read_string_from_terminal();
    printf("Output \n %s", input);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: `realloc(input, (sizeof(char))); //allocate more memory` This comment is wrong. Reallocating 1 byte to 1 byte is allocating no more memory. Ignoreing what is returned from `realloc()` is also bad.

Comment: Also don't forget to allocate space for the terminator.

Comment: This seems to work:    `realloc(input, (sizeof(char)*length+1)); `

Comment: @t1msu *This seems to work: `realloc(input, (sizeof(char)*length+1));`*  And what do you assign the returned pointed to?  Also, `getchar()` returns `int`, not `char`.

Comment: Do not cast the return value of malloc and friends.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`realloc(input, (sizeof(char))); //allocate more memory` only allocates 1 `char`.  Not 1 *more* `char`.  [@MikeCAT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37839153/c-read-string-into-dynamic-array/37840700#comment63139211_37839153)

`(sizeof(char)*length+1)` is semantically wrong.  Should be `(sizeof(char)*(length+1))`, but since `sizeof (char) == 1`, it makes no functional difference.

Need space for the null character. [@MikeCAT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37839153/c-read-string-into-dynamic-array/37840700#comment63139299_37839153)

Should test for reallocation failure.

`char c` is insufficient to distinguish all 257 different responses from `getchar()`.  Use `int`.  `getchar()` may return `EOF`.  [@Andrew Henle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37839153/c-read-string-into-dynamic-array/37840700#comment63139454_37839153)

Minor: Better to use `size_t` for array indexes than `int`.  `int` maybe too narrow.

In the end code needs to do something like:

```
size_t length = 0;
char *input = malloc(1);
assert(input); 
int c;
...
while((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF) {
  char *t = realloc(input, length + 1);
  assert(t); 
  input = t;
  input[length++] = c;
}
...
return input;

int main(void) {
  ...
  input = read_string_from_terminal();
  printf("Output \n %s", input);
  free(input);
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: On a side note, code should return `NULL` is the very first `getchar()` returns `EOF` to indicate to the calling code end-of-file.